# Try to loading multiples pugins in config but only the last one is loaded

Tags: ckeditor4.x

On CKeditor4, I have created different plugins and loaded them in config but only the last one is loaded. In the following case, only plugin3 is loaded. When i load each plugin individually each one works:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. 
    config.language = 'en';

    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
        { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
        { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
        { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
        { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
        { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
        { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
        { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] }
    ];

    config.removeButtons = 'Save,Preview,Print,Templates,Form,HiddenField,Flash,Iframe';

    config.extraPlugins = 'plugin1';
    config.extraPlugins = 'plugin2';
    config.extraPlugins = 'plugin3';
};
```

The code of three plugins is similar :

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'plugin1', {
    icons: 'plugin1',
    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.addCommand( 'insertPlugin1', {
            exec: function( editor ) {
                editor.insertHtml( '[bbcode1][/bbcode1]' );
            }
        });
        editor.ui.addButton( 'Plugin1', {
            label: 'Insert things',
            command: 'insertPlugin1',
            toolbar: 'insert'
        });
    }
});
```

Why it behaves like that? How to load all extra plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, read the docs first: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-extraPlugins

```
config.extraPlugins = 'plugin1,plugin2,plugin3';
```